# I keep getting a "scriptcs" error in my C# code for Unity. Nothing I've seen on the internet is working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CarDrive : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializedField] float steerSpeed = 1f;
    [SerializedField] float moveSpeed = 0.02f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float steerAmount = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * steerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        float moveAmount = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(0,moveAmount,0);
        transform.Rotate(0,0,-steerAmount);
        
    }
}
```

and here is the error:

'scriptcs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before, you need to either just save the script manually or go in `edit` and then `preferences` and then `project files` and `regenerate`.

Comment: How do I save the script manually?